# Spotlight search based OSX app

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, spotlight

I've been on the iOS side alot, and was thinking about a **mac app**.

There isnt much interface to it.

The app is a reference app, with data thats searchable. there are about 300 items.

I want the app to:

1. Be searchable in the Spotlight. Typing in spotlight should bring about that item(s) from the app
2. Searching an Image and hovering over it with the mouse will bring about a small display window for that image or textfile, showing its contents. I wanted something similar, though the app would Not be a textfile based app, but I'd like the native OS to show a sample window.

a native window like this.

For example searching for an xml file and hovering over an item would bring out a sample window. 
I want my customised window to appear for that but to act in a similar fashion.
[image]
I'm not sure if I've conveyed my question well enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create a [QuickLook](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/Quicklook_Programming_Guide/Articles/QLImplementationOverview.html) plugin and register it with the system. Spotlight uses QuickLook to render the previews of items it finds.

You may also need to create a [Spotlight Importer](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Carbon/Conceptual/MDImporters/Concepts/WritingAnImp.html) to tell Spotlight how to index your data.

Comment: +1 You will also need to create a [Spotlight Importer](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Carbon/Conceptual/MDImporters/Concepts/WritingAnImp.html).

Comment: @AndrewMadsen You also da Man!